# how to insert nested object into another object

Tags: javascript

guys

I am trying to insert 'price key/value' to the below newData.

I can do it with array map() and filter() but it seems little ugly.

Is there any more elegant way?

Thank you in advance!

Before

```
  public data = {
    usa: {stats: { city: 'chicago'}, price: 35},
    japan: {stats: { city: 'tokyo'}, price: 38},
    korea: {stats: { city: 'seoul'}, price: 34},
  }
```

After

```
  public newData = {
    usa: {stats: { city: 'chicago', price: 35}, price: 35},
    japan: {stats: { city: 'tokyo', price: 38}, price: 38},
    korea: {stats: { city: 'seoul', price: 34}, price: 34},
  }
```

Comment: "I can do it with array map() and filter()". Let's have a look then.

Comment: You don't need `filter`. You can do it with `forEach()`.

Comment: Why do you need the price in two places?

Comment: @Barmar I don't need them in two places...

Comment: But your result has it in two places. The 2nd-level object and the 3rd-level object.

Comment: @Barmar I just didn't remove them...

Comment: Use `Object.fromEntries`, `Object.entries, and `map()`

Comment: Or just a `for` loop.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, thank you. I will try with Object.fromEntries

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the object with a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

**Here's what that would look like in your example:**

```js
let newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) // Creating a clone of the object

for (let key in newData){ 
  newData[key].stats.price = newData[key].price 
}
```

**Full code:**

```js
let data = {
  usa: {stats: { city: 'chicago'}, price: 35},
  japan: {stats: { city: 'tokyo'}, price: 38},
  korea: {stats: { city: 'seoul'}, price: 34},
}

let newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

for (let key in newData){
  newData[key].stats.price = newData[key].price
}

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Note that the question asks for a *new* object (maybe intentionally; maybe not). This delivers the *same* object (tree) with additional properties.

Comment: @PeterB Yep, I see that now, I've made an edit to my post.